# Can a Windows Time Limit App, bump a game out of Full Screen (DirectX?) mode when time is up?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, directx

I work on software that keeps track of time (C++/MFC), and when time is up (after a handful of warnings as the time limit approaches), we need to bump the person off of the computer.

Works great with Windows apps, however, it seems that a fair number of games, typically when they are in full screen mode, can be played even after we've done our work to hide other windows and/or swap to another desktop.

I know nothing about DirectX, and since I know nothing about it, I'm eager to blame it. :-)

My assumption is that when in some kind of "DirectX" mode, the game is interacting with the hardware and whatever the Windows API is doing, the game and the video hardware could care less.

The problem is that I have unhappy parents who thought our software was going to be effective at getting little Jimmy out in the sunlight to play, and it's not.

Is there a way that my Windows App can give the game "the boot" when time is up, forcing the Windows desktop to be displayed, pausing the game, or at least detecting that we're in a hopeless situation with the display mode being in full-screen DirectX mode which can't be programatically switched out of?

Comment: The first thing little Jimmy is going to learn is how to bypass your software. Or you can just call `LockWorkStation` and tell the parents you did what you could and they should be more responsible about raising their kids.

Comment: Interesting, which method did you use right now?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/184302/how-can-i-limit-the-usage-time-for-an-user-profile-in-windows. You're not the first to write such software.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this isn't exceptionally hard. The most obvious thing to do would be to send the game a few messages. There are quite a few games which will respond to `WM_QUIT`. A bit more drastic is `LockWorkStation()`. If that fails, `TerminateProcess` works at the core OS level and ignores details like DirectX.